# How to hide—not remove—windows entry from the Ubuntu boot loader?

Tags: windows

Currently I am using Ubuntu and Windows simultaneously. But I want to hide the Windows entry from Ubuntu boot loader so that my little brother who is very prone to gaming can’t get to it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your exact question, if you have 2 hard drives, what I would do is to delete the windows entry from the bootloader and then every time you want to use windows you select it from the Bios boot order menu.

However, the easiest and probably smartest thing to do, is to add a password to windows. That is the sensible approach in my opinion.